How to prevent increasing lag in HLS Video Stream playback due to buffering and system slowdowns?
I am playing an HLS stream using the video element and Hls.js. However, I am encountering an issue where the video playback gradually lags behind the live stream. This lag is caused by occasional stutters, buffering, and system slowdowns. When these events occur, the video resumes from where it left off, causing the stream to get further ahead over time.
To compensate for this increasing lag, I tried seeking the video to the current stream position using video.currentTime, whenever new segment is downloaded (1-5s) hls.on(Hls.Events.BUFFER_APPENDED, ...), but that unfortunately creates a massive freeze (~1.2s), which is not optimal.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
const video = document.getElementById('video')
const hls = new Hls()

hls.loadSource('http://example.com/playlist.m3u8')
hls.attachMedia(video)

hls.on(Hls.Events.BUFFER_APPENDED, (name, data) => {
  const bufferLength = getBufferLength(video, data)
  // seek to play the latest segment
  video.currentTime = Math.max(video.duration - bufferLength, 0)
})

function getBufferLength(video, data) {
  // returns the last segment length + some additional buffer to avoid stuttering
}

I also tried increasing the playback rate using video.playbackRate = 1.1, which looked nice and seamless. Only when the buffer got exhausted it then paused for a short time (shorter than seeking) until new segment got loaded. Unfortunately the increased playback rate may create uncomfortable experience, especially in a real-time camera footage scenario. Setting more conservative and less noticeable playback rate however proven insufficient due to the amount of time buildup caused by the other events.
So the question is, how can I solve it in most user-friendly and convenient way and what is the widely accepted industry standard?

Firstly, you should know that if you actually care about being close to realtime, you're using the fundamentally wrong technology.  No chunked method will get you realtime, as that's not what it's designed to do.  The whole point is to record chunks that can be distributed and cached via CDNs and other normal HTTP servers.

This lag is caused by occasional stutters, buffering, and system slowdowns. When these events occur, the video resumes from where it left off, causing the stream to get further ahead over time.

Well, yeah, that's what's it's supposed to do.  It's giving the player a bit more of a buffer to prevent stream glitches.  The player estimates how much it needs to buffer, and due to these buffer underruns, it's decided that it needs a larger buffer.

To compensate for this increasing lag, I tried seeking the video to the current stream position...

Not enough data was buffered, so if you try to jerk it forward and there isn't enough data, it's just going to have to buffer more.  You can't seek to something you don't have yet.  Keep in mind, chunks may not necessarily be independently decodable.  Some chunks may depend on other chunks, if that's how the encoder is configured.

I also tried increasing the playback rate using video.playbackRate = 1.1, which looked nice and seamless. Only when the buffer got exhausted it then paused for a short time (shorter than seeking) until new segment got loaded. Unfortunately the increased playback rate may create uncomfortable experience...

I'm really not sure what you expect then.  You want to catch up closer to the live head, but you've found that you can't just skip to it reliably.  You've also decided that drifting to it with a higher playback rate is unacceptable.  This is just a matter of physics... you have to catch up somehow.  Simply not falling behind is not an option, as there will always be some reason for clients to fall behind.

So the question is, how can I solve it in most user-friendly and convenient way and what is the widely accepted industry standard?

Firstly, make sure whatever problem you're having is not on the source/encoder/upload side of things.  Assuming that your stream is all good and encoded properly, and assuming that the clients actually do have enough CPU and bandwidth to play back this stream...
Configure HLS.js for a low latency realtime stream:
lowLatencyMode: true

This essentially does what you've already tried.  It increases the playback rate to try to drift closer to the live head when possible.  If it gets behind by some certain threshold, then it restarts playback and tries to get as close as it can by seeking.
